# How do I delete a notion page in a database?

Tags: javascript, notion-api

According to the API, we delete a page by switching "archived" to true.  My code is as follows:

```
//in async
await notion.pages.update({page_id: idVar, archived: true});
```

but no dice.  I can set parameters and whatnot, but this particular property doesn't seem to work.

Edit: Thanks guys, code worked fine after updating the API!

Comment: That is how you archive (delete) a page. The block for that page cannot be deleted from the database, however, since [blocks cannot be deleted from the API](https://developers.notion.com/docs/working-with-page-content#:~:text=Deleting%20and%20updating%20blocks%20is%20not%20currently%20available).

Comment: Have you checked the return value? See https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I updated notion's js package. Seems like it's working properly with version 0.2.3 of @notionhq/client. When I was running version 0.2.0 it wouldn't work properly.